# python sleekxmpp ping error

Tags: python, xmpp, ping

When I run the ping example from [github](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/blob/develop/examples/ping.py), I get this `AttributeError`:

```
INFO     Negotiating TLS
INFO     Using SSL version: 1
INFO     Node set to: beast@home-server/50182ab4
INFO     CERT: Time until certificate expiration: 1635 days, 15:10:17.248035
INFO     Waiting for </stream:stream> from server
ERROR    Error processing event handler: <bound method PingTest.start of <__main__.PingTest object at 0x12cded0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sleekxmpp/xmlstream/xmlstream.py", line 1659, in _event_runner
    func(*args)
  File "sleekxmpp_ping.py", line 67, in start
    rtt = self['xep_0199'].ping(self.pingjid, timeout=10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sleekxmpp/plugins/base.py", line 304, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, key)
AttributeError: 'XEP_0199' object has no attribute 'ping'
ERROR    'XEP_0199' object has no attribute 'ping'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sleekxmpp/xmlstream/xmlstream.py", line 1659, in _event_runner
    func(*args)
  File "sleekxmpp_ping.py", line 67, in start
    rtt = self['xep_0199'].ping(self.pingjid, timeout=10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sleekxmpp/plugins/base.py", line 304, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, key)
AttributeError: 'XEP_0199' object has no attribute 'ping'
Done
```

I'm running sleekxmpp 1.1.11. Anybody shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

The `ping` method was added in [this commit](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/commit/3423589ba1fc2a6284bf3e4bd7402f1e80fff275), and first appeared in sleekxmpp version 1.2.0.

Comment: Upgraded to sleekxmpp 1.2.4. Now it wont even aunthenticate.
Gives CERT Error.

Comment: That should probably be a second question.  I've got the answer queued up for you.